# Is it possible to change the text of Update button in the Asp.Net GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

When we give "ShowEditButton = true" in Command Field column in a GridView. It shows the Update and Cancel button. Is it possible to change the text of "Update" button? Instead of Update and Cancel, I want to display as "Confirm and Cancel". Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the `CommandField`.

Look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.edittext.aspx